# What does it mean to accept or donate a proton?

Tags: ph, protons

I've been trying to find out the answer to this question but can't seem to find it anywhere. *I would like a very simple explanation.*

Comment: Give me 100$, and I will explain you.

Comment: Think of it kind of like mugging: the mugger (base) “accepts” a wallet (proton) from a victim (who had a relatively easily swiped wallet). So the victim “donates” the wallet to the mugger.

Comment: @Ed Great minds think alike, they say.

Comment: Just to be clear, something acting as an acid in water *cannot* just have a bond break, *spontaneously* and without an *agent*, resulting in a proton being tossed out into the solvent! **Breaking a bond takes energy** and the separation of the positively charged proton, and the negatively charged remainder, is **not** energenically favored! The moiety that *takes* the proton, i.e., the base, *actively* takes the proton from the acid moiety! Strong acids are easy prey: even water, as *pathetic* as it is as a base, is almost 100% effective in taking protons from strong acids in water.

Comment: Weak acids actually are hard to steal from: a weak acid in water is mostly intact. At any given instant in time, only a small percentage of weak acid in water exists as the conjugate base, i.e., the remainders after protons have been taken by water molecules. Most of the weak acid exists as molecules of the weak acid, just like when it was added to water. So weak acids are actually **bad** mugging victims: the large majority, at any given time, hold on to their protons when they are in water. Bases **take** protons from acids and acids do **not** just toss protons to the solvent crowd!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Donate a proton (acting as an acid)**

A covalent bond with hydrogen breaks, hydrogen leaves without electrons (as a hydrogen ion, sometimes called proton as a shorthand), and the two electrons from the bond remain with the remainder of the substance (typically in form of a lone pair).

**Accept a proton (acting as a base)**

A substance makes a new covalent bond with a hydrogen ion, providing both electrons (typically, a lone pair turns into the bond with hydrogen).